# SpringBatch SpelEvaluationException Method cannot be found on ChunkProcessorChunkHandler

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-batch, amqp

I have a SpringBatch job that performs remote chunking via RabbitMQ
Basically, there are two apps master and worker each a spring-boot application. 
Following master configuration:

```
@Bean
public DirectChannel requestsToWorkers() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow outboundFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(requestsToWorkers())
            .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(configurableRabbitTemplate).routingKey("master-route"))
            .get();
}

@Bean
public QueueChannel repliesFromWorkers() {
    return new QueueChannel();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inboundFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(configurableRabbitMqConnectionFactory, messageBrokerProperties.getMessageQueue().getQueueName()))
            .channel(repliesFromWorkers())
            .get();
}

@Bean
public ItemReader<Integer> testIntegerItemReader() {
    return () -> new Random().nextInt();
}

@Bean
public ItemWriter<Integer> testAqmpItemWriter() {
    final MessagingTemplate messagingTemplate = new MessagingTemplate();
    messagingTemplate.setDefaultChannel(requestsToWorkers());
    messagingTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(3000);
    final ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter<Integer> chunkMessageChannelItemWriter = new ChunkMessageChannelItemWriter<>();
    chunkMessageChannelItemWriter.setMessagingOperations(messagingTemplate);
    chunkMessageChannelItemWriter.setReplyChannel(repliesFromWorkers());
    return chunkMessageChannelItemWriter;
}

@Bean
public Job testJob(final ItemReader<Integer> testIntegerItemReader,
                   final ItemWriter<Integer> testAqmpItemWriter) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("testJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(
                    stepBuilderFactory.get("masterStep")
                            .<Integer, Integer>chunk(1)
                            .reader(testIntegerItemReader)
                            .writer(testAqmpItemWriter)
                            .build()
            )
            .build();
}
```

and appropriate worker configuration:

```
@Bean
public DirectChannel requestsChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public DirectChannel repliesChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inboundFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(configurableRabbitMqConnectionFactory, messageBrokerProperties.getMessageQueue().getQueueName()))
            .channel(requestsChannel())
            .get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow outboundFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(repliesChannel())
            .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(configurableRabbitTemplate).routingKey("worker-route"))
            .get();
}

@Bean
public ItemProcessor<Integer, Integer> processor() {
    return account -> {
        System.out.println("Processed random int " + account);
        return account;
    };
}

@Bean
public ItemWriter<Integer> writer() {
    return response -> System.out.println("Value written to AMQP " + response);
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "requestsChannel", outputChannel = "repliesChannel")
public ChunkProcessorChunkHandler<Integer> chunkProcessorChunkHandler(final ItemProcessor<Integer, Integer> processor,
                                                                      final ItemWriter<Integer> writer) {
    final SimpleChunkProcessor<Integer, Integer> chunkProcessor = new SimpleChunkProcessor<>(processor, writer);
    final ChunkProcessorChunkHandler<Integer> chunkProcessorChunkHandler = new ChunkProcessorChunkHandler<>();
    chunkProcessorChunkHandler.setChunkProcessor(chunkProcessor);
    return chunkProcessorChunkHandler;
}
```

Each module uses SpringBoot 2.1.2.
Overall everything looks fine and chunks of data are sending from master to worker via RabbitMQ successfully, but when a worker tries to actually read a message, I receive the following exception

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1613) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1517) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1440) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1428) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1423) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1372) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:870) [spring-rabbit-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:854) [spring-rabbit-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:78) [spring-rabbit-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1137) [spring-rabbit-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1043) [spring-rabbit-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E: Method call: Method handleChunk(byte[]) cannot be found on type org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.ChunkProcessorChunkHandler
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:109) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:93) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:123) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:162) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:431) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.doProduceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:284) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:265) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:223) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:129) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:162) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109) ~[spring-messaging-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:205) ~[spring-integration-core-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.access$600(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:57) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.createAndSend(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:237) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:204) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1514) ~[spring-rabbit-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
... 10 common frames omitted
```

already spent a lot of time on this issue
will be really grateful for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`handleChunk` expects a `ChunkRequest`, not a `byte[]` so it looks like something is going wrong with deserialization in the inbound channel adapter. It should have a `SimpleMessageConverter` (the default) which handles `java.io.Serializable` (which the `ChunkRequest` implements).

This can happen if there is no content-type message property (that converter just returns a `byte[]` if it doesn't understand the content type).

The outbound adapter uses the same converter so it should be set up ok.

Take a look at a message on the Rabbit Management UI to make sure the headers are correct. It should have this value `application/x-java-serialized-object`.

You can also examine the messages and headers by enabling debug logging.

Comment: Thank's for your response.
I double-checked everything and Content-Type header is present in the rabbit message
Even more, I tried to pass simple JSON, provided required Jackson2JsonMessageConverter, but the issue is still present

Comment: Can you run it in a debugger abd set a breakpoint in `AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.Listener.createMessage()`? The payload conversion is performed by the first line in that method. Perhaps step into the `fromMessage` method to see what's going on.

Comment: You were right, the issue was related to message converters.
I made one mistake here, I specified message converter on the AmqpTemplate configuration level when should do this on the master itemWriter level ( `messagingTemplate.setMessageConverters(new SimpleMessageConverter)` )
Thank you for help